# Why got a error "Irregular whitespace not allowed" and How to solve?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have `<p>` tag two tag like this code below, and then I run after that I got `"error Irregular whitespace not allowed  no-irregular-whitespace"`.

How can I can I fix?

```
<div>
<p>Ankjjdhd asas a sds qwe vsdf fsf ewth lioy nfhfgh</p>
<p>sdfsdf ytjyj rtyrty ddgf gsdfgsf ​​in asdsadbfd</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It comes from your ESLint rules, try to automatically fix it with VSCode (or other IDE) ESLint plugin

Answer (score 1):

It's a Eslint error which can be fixed by adding `"extends": "eslint:recommended"` line in you'r Eslint plugin config file.

[Here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-irregular-whitespace) is a link to the error page from Eslint official web page.